# Nodejs video stream not playing on iOS

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, iphone

I'm trying to stream video from nodejs server in chunks which works well on desktop and android but when I try to play on ios(iphone) it's not even requesting for partial content at all. I tried taking reference from [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/streaming-video-in-safari/) even tho it works but it plays video in broadcast mode and shows native controls as well which I've set hidden on react.

```
exports.stream = (req, res) => {
  const range = req.headers.range;
  const id = req.query.id;
  // console.log(id, typeof(id))
  if (!range || id == 'null') {
    return res.status(400).send("Requires Range Header and ID");
  }
  let videoPath = metadata[id].location;
  let videoSize = fs.statSync(metadata[id].location).size;
  const CHUNK_SIZE = (10 ** 6) / 2; // 1MB
  const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);

  // Create headers
  const contentLength = end - start + 1;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": contentLength,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
  };

  // HTTP Status 206 for Partial Content
  res.writeHead(206, headers);
  // create video read stream for this particular chunk
  const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });
  // Stream the video chunk to the client
  videoStream.pipe(res);
};
```

Here is sample page I was trying on

```
function Test () {
    return (
        <>
            <video width={'100%'} controls={false}>
                <source src={`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/video?id=8`} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

I tried debugging on backend controller and I doubt it's not even sending request for partial content ideal behavior was to play the video but it didn't play on ios(both safari and chrome).